# Vue.js vuetify v-textarea not auto growing correctly inside v-layout that's un expanded

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'd like the v-textarea to grow and shrink according to how much text is placed in it, but I'm having this issue below with a v-textarea that is inside a v-layout that is closed (not expanded).

using this

```
<v-flex md8 px-1 offset-md2>
   <v-textarea v-model="comments" @input="inputComments" rows="1" auto-grow :disabled="!editMode"></v-textarea>
</v-flex>
```

the field only shows 1 row and doesn't auto-grow. You can see the 2nd line is NOT showing completely.

[image]

and when I remove "rows="1" then this is what I see (extra white space) because the default rows is 5 for a textarea

[image]

Isn't there a way to get it to autogrow based on the lines of text or maybe re auto-grow it after it is expanded? I thought that was how it was supposed to work, but I could be wrong!

FYI - this textarea is in a hidden section, it only displays if the section is expanded. The other textareas I have on the page (not in a expanded area) show/auto-grow just fine!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have had a similar problem, and solved it by setting the `key` attribute of the `v-textarea` to a variable and changing said variable manually, forcing the component to re-render. After the re-render, `auto-grow` worked correctly.

```
<template>
  <v-textarea
    :key="autoGrowHack"
    v-model="textAreaVal"
    auto-grow
  ></v-textarea>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      autoGrowHack: false,
      textAreaVal: "lorem ipsum",
    }
  },
  methods: {
    forceReRender() {
      this.autoGrowHack = !this.autoGrowHack;
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

As far as when to call the `forceReRender` function, that's going to depend on specifics in your code. I was using this `v-textarea` inside a component on a `v-stepper` tab, and found that triggering the switch when the `v-stepper`'s step is changed to the one with this component on it made it work.

I'm guessing this is related to the following open bug on vuetify that also relates to auto-grow: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/6995

Comment: that worked! just curious as I'm a newbie to Vue, what is the key property?

Comment: `key` is how vue keeps track of DOM elements, it's more or less a unique identifier (I'm not totally clear on the specifics myself). It's needed in `v-for` directives so that vue can tell the generated DOM elements apart; you also need to set it manually when using transitions if the HTML tag on either side of the transition is the same, because in that case with no `key`, vue thinks it's just the same DOM element so it won't do the transition.

So if you manually change the key on a DOM element, to Vue, it's like you deleted one and created another, and it will re-render the whole thing.

Comment: Better information can be found in the [Vue docs on key](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#key)

Comment: This is a useful explainer: https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/

Answer (score 8):

I had similar issue when **v-textarea** with **auto-grow** is inside of *v-expansion-panel-content*

Just wrap it with **v-lazy** component and **auto-grow** should work as expected

```
 <v-expansion-panel-content>
    <v-lazy>
      <v-textarea
       :key="autoGrowHack"
       v-model="textAreaVal"
       auto-grow
      ></v-textarea>
   </v-lazy>
 </v-expansion-panel-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case `v-textrea` is hidden sometimes and when it's shown again it height doesn't get calculated properly;

Found nothing better than

```
<template>
  <!-- . . . . .-->
    <v-textarea
      ref="vTextarea"
      :value="vTextareaValue"
      auto-grow
      hide-details
      rows="1"
      single-line
    />
</template>
<script>
export default Vue.extend({
  data() {
    return {
      vTextareaWasMounted: false,
    };
  },
  updated: function () {
    let vTextAreaMounted = !!this.$refs.vTextarea;
    
    
    if (vTextAreaMounted && !this.vTextareaWasMounted) {
    
      let delays = [30, 60, 100, 200];
    
      delays.map((delay) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (this.$refs.vTextarea) {
            console.log(this.$options.name + ': vTextarea force calculateInputHeight')
            this.$refs.vTextarea.calculateInputHeight();
          }
        }, delay)
      });
    }

    this.textareaWasMounted = vTextAreaMounted;
  },
});
</script>
```

Timers are ugly but I don't know how to improve this solution yet

Answer (score 0):

I also stumbled upon this issue, which seems to be related to this https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/6995.

Here's what I did:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <v-textarea
            ...
            maxlength="1024" :rows="rows" auto-grow
            :disabled="isDisabled"
            ...
        >
        </v-textarea>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: "MyComponent",
        props: {
            isDisabled: {
                type: Boolean
            },
        },
        data() {
            return {
                rows: 3,
        },
    },
    mounted() {
        if (this.isDisabled) {
            this.rows = 5;
        }
    },
</script>
```

In my case I have a prop `isDisabled` that checked if `v-textarea` should be disabled or not. Because I use a `v-stepper` and this component is not the first one shown, the autogrow bug kicks in.
Originally, `v-textarea` should've been only 3 rows and would expand based on how many characters there are.

I created a new property `rows` and set it to a default value.
When the prop `isDisabled` is `true`, I change the value of `rows` to `5` when the component is mounted. I chose the value `5` because the `1024` allowed characters seem to fit in just fine in my case.

Hope someome finds this useful!

Answer (score 0):

I appreciated the other answers but wasn't fully satisfied because they were causing flashing or were delayed due to timers, etc.

What I did was use the v-resize directive to capture when the window resizes and then call calculateInputHeight(). For example, here is a template:

```html
<div ref="container">
  <v-textarea :value="longText"
              label="Text"
              rows="1"
              auto-grow
              filled
              hide-details
              class="ma-4"
              ref="textarea"              
              v-resize="onWindowResized"></v-textarea>
</div>
```

And the component code:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
    textareaWidth: undefined,
    longText: [...Array(26)].map((el, i) => String.fromCharCode(97 + i).repeat(10)).join(' ')
  },
  methods: {
    onWindowResized() {
      let textareaWidth = this.$refs.container && this.$refs.container.offsetWidth;
      if (textareaWidth !== this.textareaWidth) {
        this.textareaWidth = textareaWidth;
        this.$refs.textarea.calculateInputHeight();
      }
    }
  }
})
```

This is allowing the text area to resize accordingly, without the flashing. Here is the full JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/CodeVirtue/t0ex7pzu/